# Convert Html to Image in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, uiwebview, uiimageview

I am working on an App which requires preview of various html files that are loaded from web. I  have a preview of those html pages.However, when the number of images increase, there is a [delay to load UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179074/delay-while-loading-locally-stored-file-on-webview) which significantly increase the time to load the app.

I am looking to by-pass it by converting the html to images(its for the purpose of preview) and then loading it on UIImageView.

How do I convert html(it might be local or web resource) to a image ?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132886/converting-html-to-image-in-ios

Comment: @user3551959, for the solution to work, I need to load it on webview, from there it will again preview it. So how will it help me ? I want something where html file will be input and image will be output (without loading that file in webview)

Comment: You can create UIWebView with html string
`webview = [[UIWebView alloc]init];`
`[webView loadHTMLString:mystring baseURL:nil];`

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179074/delay-while-loading-locally-stored-file-on-webview